# Видимость данных в функции

Tags: php, функции

Нужно заставиь функцию видеть
обьект созданый вне, без
передачи его как параметра. Как
можно решить данную
проблему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`global` это плохо. Это костыль из древности. Необходимость его использования, говорит о том, что вы делаете что то не правильно.

Есть куча вариантов обойди глобальные переменные

1. Статические классы
2. Паттерны `Registry` и `Service Locator`, `Dependency Injection`
3. Замыкания

   ```
   $closure = function() use ($string) { echo $string; };
   ```

Выбирайте любое решение, в зависимости от конкретной задачи.

Answer (score 3):

Неужели эта информация исчезла из руководства по языку? А, нет, есть всё-таки...

Руководство по PHP > Справочник языка > Переменные > [Область видимости переменной#Ключевое слово global](https://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global).